# CSS: same div, 2 different styles (for differing child divs)

Tags: html, css

I have a div. Inside this div are 2 smaller divs. I want one of the smaller divs to have `overflow:visible`, and the other to have `overflow:hidden`. Can't figure out what selectors allow me to do this, I think I'm missing something super simple.

**edit** Sorry, let me rephrase that: I want the main div to have the style `overflow:visible` only applied to one of the child divs, while the main div also has the style `overflow:hidden` apply to the other.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3fQBt/

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="visible">This div should be visible.</div>
  <div id="hidden">This div should be hidden.</div>
</div>

#body{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:20px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  overflow:visible;
}

#visible{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:-20px; //this should overflow visibly
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}

#hidden{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:-20px; //this should be hidden
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: It's still not really clear what you want to see. Could you create an image of the desired result?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/z5M8Lq2.png See where the blue div overflows off the left of its red parent div? I'd like that to be hidden (while maintaining visibility of the green div's overflow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this should get you going in the right direction.

```
<div id="body">
 <div id="visible">This div should overflow.</div>
 <div id="hidden-box">
  <div id="hidden">This div shouldn't.</div>
 </div>
</div>


#hidden-box {position:relative;overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;}
```

Comment: Good thinking, I this is the only way that I can think of

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of solutions:

HTML:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="visible">This div should overflow.</div>

    <div id="hidden1">This div shouldn't.</div>

    <div id="clip">
        <div id="hidden2">This div shouldn't.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* solution 1 uses text-indent to create the clipping and a red block to cover the excess background blue on the right */

#hidden1 {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#00f;
    color:#fff;
    text-indent: -20px;

    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#hidden1:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}


/* solution 2 uses a second div with overflow: hidden to clip the text to get around the parent div's overflow: visible */

#clip {
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}

#hidden2{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#00f;
    color:#fff;
    margin-left:-20px;

    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2cQqG/)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you reduce de `width` of the second div and remove the negative `margin-left` like this:

```
#hidden{
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j66tE/)

**EDIT:** Added calc() on CSS

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't work with my actual project... that'd just be a fix for this example. I caught the answer you deleted before though, having to do with first-child and last-child, and I think that might work. I just have an indefinite amount of "last-children" I'm dealing with.

Comment: My first answer wouldn't work because the CSS would only affect the inside of the selected div. What you want is to have different CSS's attributes in different regions of the same element and this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, although it's pretty brittle, so not much use in the real world:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

*, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {margin: 0;}
#body{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#f00;
    margin:20px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:solid 1px #000;
}

#visible{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#0f0;
    position:fixed;
    left: 0;
}

#hidden{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#00f;
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: -20px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="body">
    <div id="visible">This div should overflow.</div>
    <div id="hidden">This div shouldn't.</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY this,

```
#hidden {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #00F;
        color: #FFF;
        /*margin-left: -20px;  <--- remove this*/
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden !important;/*add this*/
    }
```

Comment: This won't allow the div to visibly overflow though, doesn't do the trick :/